# How to clean varnish cache when it's storage is fulled?

Tags: varnish

I'm using varnish3.0.6 version.

Assign memory 7G to varnish storage. Few days check status found it full.

[image]

I run varnishstat get below information:

[image]
I didn't found n_lru_nuked line. it means cache only add not clean?

I found this in varnish [document page](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ArchitectureLRU).

Question is: *How to use this to release varnish cache?*

Comment: You will see n_lru_nuked if you do a `varnishstat -1` instead of the interactive version that is limited to the rows in your terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to flush all cache from command line. You can try with this

```
varnishadm "ban req.url ~ /"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to release the varnish cache by restarting the daemon.

On Redhat variations:

```
sudo systemctl stop varnish
sudo systemctl start varnish
```

Ubuntu:

```
sudo service varnish restart
```